# Is QListView right for me?

Tags: qt, qlistview

I've been having difficulty trying to find a Qt widget that will allow me to display a list with columns. From what I understand, QListView does indeed display list data, but it doesn't allow for programmers to add a list view header -- in fact, it appears the only widget that does allow one to display headers is QTreeView (which, quite frankly, is a pain in the arse to work with).

Qt certainly must offer an easy way to display a header and data organized by columns, no?

Thanks so much!
--Dany.

Comment: Why do you think QTreeView is so bad?  Surely it's the tree _models_ that get complicated, not the tree view used with a list or table model?

Answer (score 4):

What about [QTableView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qtableview.html) or [QTableWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtablewidget.html)?  You can make it look a little more like a list with columns by hiding the grid and the left header.

Answer (score 4):

Straight from the QListView's docs:

> This view does not display horizontal or vertical headers; to display a list of items with a horizontal header, use QTreeView instead.